# Pass hybrid dictionary keys to Excel range

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I am attempting to dump hybrid dictionary keys to an excel worksheet range, but it is not performing as expected. Here's my code.

```
    Dim ExcelApplication As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add
    Dim SheetName As String = "Area Information"
    Dim ExcelAreaBalanceWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim BAGenByKVDictionary As New HybridDictionary

   'code to populate hybriddictionary

    Dim Rng As Excel.Range = ExcelAreaBalanceWorksheet.Range("a1", _
                ExcelAreaBalanceWorksheet.Cells(BAGenByKVDictionary.Count, 1))
    Rng.Value = ExcelApplication.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BAGenByKVDictionary.Keys.ToString)
```

When I try to pass the keys to Excel, it passes `System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection` for all cells instead of passing the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ToString() on the [HybridDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary_methods.aspx) does not override the base `Object` implementation, [which is defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx), in part as:

> The default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully
>   qualified name of the type of the Object...

In order to retrieve the keys as an array of strings, there are numerous methods, but I always prefer the most straightforward approach, a loop:

```
    Dim sbKeys As New System.Text.StringBuilder(1000)

    For Each oKey As Object In BAGenByKVDictionary.Keys
        ' Produce a comma=separated list
        If sbKeys.Length <> 0 Then
            sbKeys.Append(",")
        End If
        sbKeys.Append(oKey.ToString())
    Next

    Rng.Value = ExcelApplication.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(sbKeys.ToString())
```

Comment: Never would have thought of that competent_tech! I've screwed up my code, so once I get it working again, I'll let you know if this works (which I'm sure it will!).